# Best word to describe "hard to overlook" or "hard to ignore"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

What is the best word to describe something positive that is hard to overlook or to ignore?

Example:

> Her passion for dancing is ______ (hard to ignore)!

To explain the background of this sentence, I am writing a card for my girlfriend for her birthday. She's a dancer & very passionate about it. For me using the word "obvious/hard to overlook" does not sound romantic/playful. I am trying to find a playful and sweet way to tell her that her passion for dancing is very much hard to ignore/overlook & it's very beautiful.

Comment: "Her passion for dancing is obvious"?

Comment: How about ***unmistakable***

Comment: There are just about infinite possible words that can fit here, which means this question is too broad.

Comment: Her passion for dancing is "plain as day."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her passion for dancing is **palpable**.

Some more replacements could be:

- irresistable
- distinct
- prominent
- remarkable
- unmistakable
- sensational

Note: I find inescapable as the right answer to replace 'hard to ignore' but contextually incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Her passion for dancing is undeniable / inescapable.

> **inescapable** adjective
>
> ​ If a fact or a situation is inescapable, it cannot be ignored or
>   avoided.

[[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inescapable)]

Answer (score 2):

> Her passion for dancing is ***unmissable***!

ODO:

> **[unmissable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unmissable)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** So clear or obvious that it cannot be missed.
>
> ‘Though the warning signs have been unmissable for years, many
>   Americans are reacting to the confirmation that there is a doping
>   scandal in baseball as if they had found maggots in Mom's apple pie.’

Answer (score 0):

"Palpable" is often used in this way, but it comes from the Latin verb *palpāre*, "to touch." So it makes sense to say, "The excitement in the arena is palpable" (i.e. one can almost feel it) but someone's passion for dancing? I'm surprised no one's recommended "apparent" or "conspicuous."